# Cannot resolve method openFileInput (Android Development)

Tags: java, android

I'm getting a 'cannot resolve method' error with the line of code:

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(fileName);
```

I'm not in an acitivty I'm in a seperate class so I'm assuming that's why it won't work. I've tried doing things like this but they still give me  the 'cannot resolve method
 error:

```
FileInputStream fis = getApplicationContext.openFileInput(fileName);
```

Thanks for any help, I'm new to android development

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar case of this, where I couldn't use `openFileInput` or `openFileOutput` while in a class that wasn't an activity. In my case, though, I was already passing the context to the method, so I just did

```
context.openFileInput("stuff.dat");
```

If you're able to do something similar, that solves it.

Comment: Any idea if there are any downsides to simply using getActivity().openFIleInput("stuff.dat"); Assuming you are not passing the context into the method.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of offhand - I'd give it a try and if it works, that's a good sign.

Answer (score 1):

Main error is due to Context please give the right context or you can pass context by using it in function.
for this you will need to pass Activity Context to it by sending Context using parametrized method as:

```
  protected void onCreate(String filename,Context context) {
  try
 {
     FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);  
     //...your code here...      
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {

 }
}
```